# Prob. 12, Sec. 30, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd edition: Every continuous open image of a first / second countable space is also first / second countable

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification, second-countable, first-countable

Here is Prob. 12, Sec. 30, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous open map. Show that if $X$ satisfies the first or the second countability axiom, then $f(X)$ satisfies the same axiom.

My Attempt:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and let $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous open map.

> Case 1. Suppose that $X$ is first-countable.

> Let $y = f(x)$ be any point in $f(X)$. Then $x \in X$, and let
> $$ \left\{ B_{x, n} \colon n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \tag{0} $$
> be a countable local basis at $x$. Then each set $B_{x, n}$ is an open set of $X$ such that $x \in B_{x, n}$, and for any open set $U$ of $X$ such that $x \in U$, there exists a set $B_{x, n_U}$ in the collection (0) such that
> $$ x \in B_{x, n_U} \subset U. \tag{1} $$

> We try to show that the countable collection
> $$ \left\{ f \left( B_{x, n} \right) \colon n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \tag{2} $$
> is a local basis at $f(x)$.

> Since $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ is an open map and since each set $B_{x, n}$ in the collection (0) above is an open set in $X$, therefore each image set $f \left( B_{x, n} \right)$ is an open set in $Y$ and hence is also an open set in the subspace $f(X)$ because $f \left( B_{x, n} \right) \subset f(X)$.

> And, since each set $B_{x, n}$ contains $x$, therefore each set $f \left( B_{x, n} \right)$ contains the point $y = f(x)$.

> Let $V$ be any open set of $f(X)$ such that $y = f(x) \in V$. Then there exists an open set $V^\prime$ of $Y$ such that
> $$ V = f(X) \cap V^\prime. $$
> Then of course $f(x) \in V^\prime$ also, which implies that $x \in f^{-1} \left( V^\prime \right)$.

> In fact we even also have
> $$
> \begin{align}
> f^{-1}(V) &= f^{-1} \left( f(X) \cap V^\prime \right) \\
> &= f^{-1} \big( f(X) \big) \cap f^{-1} \left( V^\prime \right) \\
> &= X \cap f^{-1} \left( V^\prime \right) \\
> &= f^{-1} \left( V^\prime \right). 
> \end{align}
> $$
> Thus we have the equality
> $$
> f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1} \left( V^\prime \right). \tag{3}
> $$
> And from the last line of the preceding paragraph we have
> $$ x \in f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1} \left( V^\prime \right).$$

> Now as $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map and as $V^\prime$ is an open set of $Y$, so the inverse image $f^{-1} \left( V^\prime \right) = f^{-1}(V)$ is also an open set of $X$. [Please refer to (3) above.]

> As $U \colon= f^{-1}(V)$ is an open set of $X$ containing $x$, so there exists a set $B_{x, n_U}$ in the collection (0) above such that the relation (1) above holds, and therefore we can conclude that
> $$ f(x) \in f \left( B_{x, n_U} \right) \subset f(U) = f\left( f^{-1} (V) \right) \subset V, $$
> that is,
> $$ f(x) \in f \left( B_{x, n_U} \right) \subset V. $$

> Thus the collection (2) is a countable local basis at the point $y = f(x) \in f(X)$.

> But $y = f(x)$ was an arbitrary point of $f(X)$. Hence $f(X)$ is first-countable.

Am I right?

> Case 2. Next, suppose that $X$ is second-countable.

> Let
> $$ \left\{  B_n \colon n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \tag{4} $$
> be a countable basis for the topology of $X$.

> Then each set $B_n$ in the collection (4) is an open set of $X$; moreover for each open set $U$ of $X$ and for each point $x \in U$, there exists a set $B_{n_{U, x}}$ in the collection (4) above such that
> $$ x \in B_{n_{U, x}} \subset U. \tag{5} $$

> We seek to show that the countable collection
> $$
> \left\{ f \left( B_n \right) \colon n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \tag{6}
> $$
> is a basis for the subspace topology of $f(X)$ regarded as a subspace of $Y$.

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now as $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ is an open map and as the set $B_n$ in the collection (4) is an open set of $X$, so we can conclude that the image set $f \left( B_n \right)$ is an open set of $Y$ and hence is also an open set of $f(X)$ because $f \left( B_n \right) \subset f(X)$. Thus the collection (6) is a collection of open sets in the subspace $f(X)$ of $Y$.

> Let $V$ be any open set of $f(X)$ and let $y$ be any point in $V$. Then there exists an open set $V^\prime$ of $Y$ such that
> $$ V = f(X) \cap V^\prime. $$
> Then of course $y \in f(X)$ and $y \in V^\prime$ which implies that $y = f(x)$ for some point $x \in X$ and that $x \in f^{-1} \left( V^\prime \right)$ also.

> As in Case 1 above we have the identity
> $$
> f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1} \left( V^\prime \right). \tag{7}
> $$
> And from the last line of the preceding paragraph we have
> $$ x \in f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1} \left( V^\prime \right) .$$

> Moreover, as $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map and as $V^\prime$ is an open set of $Y$, so the set  $f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1} \left( V^\prime \right)$ is an open set of $X$; let us put
> $$ U \colon= f^{-1}(V). \tag{8} $$
> [Please refer to (7) above.]
> Then $U$ is an open set of $X$ such that $x \in U$. So there exists a set $B_{n_{U, x}}$ in the collection (4) above such that (5) above holds.

> From (5) and (8) above we obtain
> $$
> y = f(x) \in f \left( B_{n_{U, x}} \right) \subset f(U) = f \left( f^{-1}(V) \right) \subset V,
> $$
> and thus
> $$
> y \in f \left( B_{n_{U, x}} \right) \subset V. \tag{9}
> $$

> Thus the countable collection (6) above is a collection of open sets in the subspace $f(X)$ of $Y$ such that for any open set $V$ of $f(X)$ and for any point $y \in V$ there exists a set in the collection (6) for which the relations in (9) above holds. Thus the collection (6) above is indeed a basis for the subspace topology of $f(X)$, by Lemma 13.2 in Munkres.

> Therefore the collection (6) is a countable basis for the topology of $f(X)$ regarded as a subspace of $Y$.

> Hence $f(X)$ (regarded as a subspace of $Y$) is second-countable.

Am I right?

Are both of my proofs are correct and clear enough presentation-wise? Or, are there problems in either one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't read the proofs for the simple reason they are way too long.

You can make them way shorter...

For example:

Suppose $X$ is second countable. Define $g: X \to f(X): x \mapsto f(x)$. By construction, $g$ is continuous, open and surjective. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a countable base for $X$. Then we claim that $g(\mathcal{B}):= \{g(B): B \in \mathcal{B}\}$ is also a countable base.

It is obvious that $|g(\mathcal{B})| \leq |\mathcal{B}|$ so $g(\mathcal{B})$ is countable. Next, let $A$ be an open in $f(X)$. Since $g$ is continuous and $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $X$, we can write $g^{-1}(A) = \bigcup \mathcal{B}_0$ for a subcollection $\mathcal{B}_0 \subseteq \mathcal{B}$. Consequently, by surjectivity of $g$

$$A = g(g^{-1}(A)) = \bigcup g(\mathcal{B}_0)$$

and we are done.